# What is the correct way to fill a __m128i parameter, from basic type (such as short), to use with _mm256_broadcast_epi (such as _mm_broadcastw_epi16)

Tags: c++, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx2

All the four _mm256_broadcastb_epi8, _mm_broadcastw_epi16, _mm256_broadcastd_epi32 and _mm256_broadcastq_epi64
functions are intrinsics for VPBROADCASTB, VPBROADCASTW, VPBROADCASTD and VPBROADCASTQ instructions accordingly.
According Intel's documentation: ["Intel® Advanced Vector Extensions Programming Reference"](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/4f/5b/36945),
those instructions may receive a 8-bit, 16-bit 32-bit, 64-bit memory location accordingly.
Page 5-230:

> The source operand is 8-bit, 16-bit 32-bit,
> 64-bit memory location or the low 8-bit, 16-bit 32-bit, 64-bit data in an XMM register

However, the intrinsic API (of Intel, MSVS and gcc) for those instructions receives a __m128i parameter.
Now if i have a variable of basic type, supposedly 'short', what is the most efficient and cross-platform way (At least between MSVS and gcc)
to pass that variable to the according broadcast intrinsic (_mm_broadcastw_epi16 in case of short)?

For Example:

```
void func1(uint8_t v) {
    __m256i a = _mm256_broadcastb_epi8(<convert_to__m128i>(v));
    ...
}

void func1(uint16t v) {
    __m256i a = _mm256_broadcastw_epi16(<convert_to__m128i>(v));
    ...
}

void func1(uint32_t v) {
    __m256i a = _mm256_broadcastd_epi32(<convert_to__m128i>(v));
    ...
}

void func1(uint64_t v) {
    __m256i a = _mm256_broadcastq_epi64(<convert_to__m128i>(v));
    ...
}
```

What should be the <convert_to__m128i> so it is most efficient and cross-platform (if possible)?

For MSVS for example one can do:

```
void func1(uint16t v) {
    __m128i vt;
    vt.m128_u16[0] = v;
    __m256i a = _mm256_broadcastw_epi16(vt);
    ...
}
```

But without optimizations it can first load a xmm register and only then use it in VPBROADCASTW.
When with optimizations it may use the memory location of v directly.
It is also only valid for MSVS.

Comment: `_mm256_set1_epi8` and friends.

Comment: FYI doing a search like this is super helpful if you know the mnemonic of the instruction and want to know which intrinsics are related to it: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#!=undefined&text=broadcastb&techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2

Comment: `_mm_broadcastb_epi8` produces an `__m128i` result, not `__m256i`.  You generally don't want it, just let the compiler emit a broadcast instruction for a `_mm256_set1_epi8` intrinsic if you have a scalar value to start with, not a `__m128i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already sequence/compound intrinsics which do exactly what you want:

```
_mm256_set1_epi8/16/32/64
```

From Intels intrinsics guide:

[Broadcast 8-bit integer a to all elements of dst. This intrinsic may generate the vpbroadcastb.](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#!=undefined&text=broadcastb&techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2&expand=4969)

Using those you then should be able to trust the compiler to generate the optimal code.

I use the Intel Intrinsics Guide when doing stuff like this which is helpful as you can reverse search from a mnemonic (in this case you knew you eventually wanted vpbroadcastb) and it'll tell you which intrinsics are related to it.

Comment: Indeed i missed the _m256_set1_epi, it looks like just what i looked for. So as it seems the _mm256_broadcast are for cases when you have a 128 bit register (xmm) to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Just let the compiler emit a broadcast instruction for a **`_mm256_set1_epi8(scalar)`** intrinsic if you have a scalar value to start with, not a `__m128i`.

---

But you generally don't want that either, `_mm_broadcastb_epi8` (`__m128i` result) or `__m256i _mm256_broadcastb_epi8(__m128i)` unless you already have a `__m128i` to start with and want the low element.

Getting a scalar into a `__m128i` without the compiler wasting instructions can be an actual problem for 8 or 16-bit scalars if you don't care about high the high 2 or 3 bytes of the low dword; it might `movzx` load into an integer register and then use `vmovd` or something terrible like that.

---

Comment: I mistakenly put the _mm_broadcastb instead of _mm256_broadcast in the example. Indeed i missed the _m256_set1_epi, it looks like just what i looked for.